# Как обрабатывать устаревшую страницу?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, jsf, primefaces

Допустим, пользователь открыл одну и ту же страницу в двух вкладка (страница обрабатывается `ViewScoped` бином). Пользователь повзаимодействовал с одной страницей, и переходит к такой же, но открытой в другой вкладке. И там бина уже нет, потому что произошло взаимодействие с другим `ViewScoped` и этот, благополучно, удалился.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как предупредить пользователя что страница устарела? Ведь никаких концов не осталось. Работаю с JSF.

SessionScope, к сожалению, не подходит.

Comment: Думаю, что идеального ответа не существует. Можно обрабатывать ошибку при обращении с устаревшей страницы на сервер (http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler - ViewExpiredException), но это будет не предупреждение заранее, а сообщение об ошибке постфактум. Можно попробовать комбинировать обработку ошибок с периодическим опросом сервера с клиента (PrimeFaces pool?), но это дополнительная нагрузка на сервер. Либо переходить на RequestScopped с сохранением параметров либо в URL либо в отдельном SessionScopped компоненте